# Why in multi-dimentional array in C/C++ a[0] is same as a?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have the following program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[3][3]={{1,2,3},
                {4,5,6},
                {7,8,9}};

    printf("%p\n",a);
    printf("%p\n",a[0]);
    printf("%p\n",*(a+0));
}
```

And it gives me the following output:

```
6356716
6356716
6356716
```

I was expecting that, given a base address such as `6356716` then `*(6356716+0)` would yield the value inside that location (i.e, `1`).

So, if an array name is equivalent to a pointer to its first value like in above expression, printing 'a' should print the pointer to its first value i.e a[0](which itself decays to its 1st element at location 6356716). In that case, why does dereferencing not work here, and `*(a+0)` evaluates to 
`*(6356716+0)`?

Comment: `C/C++ == UB` please pick one language

Comment: Nothing in this code is actually referring to the *value* (i.e. 1). Second and third prints are equivalent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: it is not the same so your question is meaningless.

Comment: Imagine this: the first (`a`) points to a train... the second (`a[0]`) points to the first carriage of the train... the last (`*(a+0)`) points to the first seat in the first carriage. They all point to the "same place", but they point to different things.

Comment: @pmg Nice analogy. It's just that `*(a+0)` is exactly same as `a[0]`.

Comment: Lol, yes @Eugenesh. But let that mistake go. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "... why dereferencing didn't work here ...." --> It did work.  What output were you expecting?

Comment: @chux! I was expecting 1 by evaluating *(6356716+0)!

Comment: `*(6356716+0)` attempts to add 2 integers and then de-reference the `sum` - this is not legal C and that is not what was done in the posted code.  What type of pointer was `6356716` to represent?  By answering that, the reason for the output should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is an array of 3 arrays of 3 `int`. When used in an expression other than as an operand of `sizeof`, unary `&`, or `_Alignof`, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first argument, which is an array of 3 `int`. If you correctly print this pointer, it will show the address of that array of 3 `int`.

`a[0]` is the first element in `a`, so it is an array of 3 `int`. When used in an expression, with the same exceptions as above, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, which is an `int`. If you correctly print this pointer, it will show the address of that `int`.

Since an array is simply a sequence of objects stored contiguously, an array starts at the same place that its first element does. Therefore, the results of printing `a` and `a[0]` show the same address.

`*(a+0)` is the same as `a[0]`, so printing it has the same result.

You should not use `%u` to print address. Printing pointers with `%u` has undefined behavior. It might appear to work in your implementation in some circumstances, but it will break in other circumstances. To print an address, use `%p` with a pointer converted to `void *` or `const void *`:

```
printf("%p\n", (const void *) a);
printf("%p\n", (const void *) a[0]);
printf("%p\n", (const void *) *(a+0));
```

Answer (score 0):

When used in

```
printf("%u\n", a);
printf("%u\n", a[0]);
```

`a` decays to the pointer to the first element of `a` and `a[0]` decays to the pointer to the first element of `a[0]`. Equivalently, you could use:

```
printf("%u\n", &a[0]);
printf("%u\n", &a[0][0]);
```

From a object type point of view, `&a`, `&a[]`, and`&a[0][0]` are completely different pointer types. However, if you look at the memory layout of a 2D array, you will realize that, from a **purely numerical point of view**, `&a` == `&a[]` == `&a[0][0]`.

Also, `"%u"` is not the correct format for printing pointers. You should use `"%p"`.

```
printf("%p\n", a);
printf("%p\n", a[0]);
```

Comment: UB:  wrong printf pointer format.  Sending the address is the same but the referenced objects are not (have different types).

Comment: @P__J__, you are right. I was addressing just the core question but I have updated the answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to understand is that a 2D array is treated as an array of arrays and all the elements of 2D array are stored in continuous memory locations,Now the second thing to understand is that an array name actually gives the address of first element in it.So your first printf statement `printf("%u\n",a);`actually gives you the address of `a[0]`,as `a[0]` is the first element in this 2D array.Now your second printf statement `printf("%u\n",a[0]);` gives you the address of `a[0][0]` , because `a[0]` is actually the name of first array in the 2D array.Now your last printf statement is `printf("%u\n",*(a+0));` is actually the way a compiler internally treats array ,it is exactly same as the second one.As from the explanation it is clear that the three statements are referring to the same address but this does not mean that they are same thing ,the first statement has a different meaning as compared to second and third as explained above.Though the three statements are giving you the address of `1`,which is the first element of the 2D array.